# How to use [FromBody] and [FromQuery] attribute at the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

In the post request,I need to get the parameters from the query string at the same time.This is my code,but can't work

```cs
 [HttpPost("test")]
 public string Test(TestRequest request)
 {
      //TODO  ...
 }


    public class TestRequest
    {
        [FromHeader(Name = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [FromQuery(Name = "traceId")]
        public string Trace { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(4)]
        public string Mark { get; set; }

        [Range(18, 35)]
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: It depends on what type of properties do you have but it is possible. Please check https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8111#issuecomment-407958780

Comment: Thanks, I found the right way from here

Answer (score 4):

You have to put the different parameters in the method signature, so it would be something like

```
[HttpPost("test/{traceId}")] // Note the query parameter 
public string Test(
    [FromHeader(Name = "id")]string id,
    [FromQuery(Name = "traceId")]string trace,
    [FromBody]Request request
    )
{
    // TODO...
}

public class Request
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Mark { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

bit depending on how your actual request looks like. This would read a Request-Object from the body, the id from the header and the traceId from the query.

Comment: Yes, I know this can be done, but I want to put the parameters into the same object.Any idea?

Comment: I don't think that is an option. You'd have to put the query/header data into the object yourself in the controller method.

Comment: @ZUOXIANGE you could still add the properties in the request class and add a `[ValidateNever]` attribute to them. Then after validating the request model and the additional two parameters, you could just assign them to the model.